# Fiber bundle over torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, vector-bundles, topological-groups, fiber-bundles

Consider the fiber bundle $X\longrightarrow S^1\times S^1 $ with fibers $\mathbb R^q$.

If $X$ is a $G$-homogeneous space, where $G$ is a simply-connected and connected Lie group i.e $G$ acts transitively on $X$. My questions:

1. Can always   $X$ be written as $G/H$ for $G$ solvable?
2. Is there any semisimple  Lie group who can act transitively on $X$?

Comment: Hint: Think of $G=SL(2,R)$ or its universal cover. Can you think of a manifold homotopy-equivalent to the circle on which $G$ acts transitively?

Comment: $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{0\}$? What about my first question?

Comment: I do not understand your first question. Is there any relation between $G$ in the 1st sentence and $G$ in the 1st question?

Comment: Sorry, I meant if $X=G/H$ for any Lie group $G$. Is $X$ isomorphic to $R/J$ for a solvable Lie group. i.e is there a solvable Lie group $R$ acting transitively on $X$?

Comment: If you give me an example of a nontrivial bundle $R^q\to E\to T^2$  whose total space is a homogeneous space, I might think about your question.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try to find one although it seems not easy since I have the feeling that the bundle tends to be trivial in most cases

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72987/discussion-between-ronald-and-moishe-cohen).